# In Flutter how to create a database and search feature?

Tags: flutter

I am making an app with flutter where the users can search for preferences about a car and the car that meets those preferences appears. So I expect I have to make a database that holds the different types of cars and their properties. But how am I suppose to create this database? Is there a specific add-on or something? Anything that can lead me to the right direction would be appreciated

P.S. I apologize if this is a basic question. I am new to programming lol

Comment: you definitely need a database to store the cars and a search service that helps you search for cars or you can filter it your own.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating database for each and every car and their specifications, look for some existing API which will allow you to get these specifications after you send some car id, or its name. Something like [this](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/). Second part will be building your application, you will need to implement a [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) client that will fetch specific data from specific endpoints via [Future method](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), you can afterwards [serialize](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) these data and either store them for user inside device with some [offline storage solution](https://pusher.com/tutorials/local-data-flutter) (if it does not collide with terms of use), or just simply render them via [TextWidget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/text) in your app.